# I can't access QuerySet in Manager's init method in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I'd like to get a QuerySet of a Model in Manager's `__init__` method to setup Pagination for the QuerySet results. The reason why I want to setup Pagination in `__init__` method is because I have lots of simple methods in the Manager like `getPage` and `getNumberOfPages` etc. to simplify abstraction and I don't want to duplicate the code to setup `Paginator` across all these methods.

For example, let's say that there is an `Article` model, which has a custom `ArticleManager` and it looks somewhat like this:

```
class ArticleManager(models.Manager):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ArticleManager, self).__init__()
        allObjects = super(ArticleManager, self).get_queryset()
        self.articlePaginator = Paginator(allObjects, 10)


class Article(models.Model):
    # blah blah
    # Model fields everywhere
    objects = ArticleManager()
```

Fourth line of this code that is `super(ArticleManager, self).get_queryset()` returns an `AttributeError` exception:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I guess I should have done something more to properly initialize the Manager, but I'm not sure what it is. I've not found anything alike I want in Django docs or in other StackOverflow questions. Also I guess there might be something wrong in my approach, so if that's the case I'd be grateful if somebody would point that out.

Comment: The manager is created when you load your application, and then it lives forever. That's not the right place to have transient state.

Comment: True. Right now I have no idea why I wanted it in init instead of making it for example a property as @Anonymous has said in his reply. I guess it's too much time spent with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the parent's `get_query()` method. You're not overriding it so there's no point, just call it on `self`. Better yet, make this operation lazy. Properties are an option:

```
class ArticleManager(models.Manager):
    @property
    def article_paginator(self):
        return Paginator(self.get_queryset(), 10)
```

Then you can access it via `Article.objects.article_paginator`.

Comment: Be careful though as accessing it several times will trigger a query every single time. As a rule, I would try to avoid using a property for something that triggers a query. A method call is more explicit about something happening.

Comment: Actually it won't trigger anything. `get_queryset()` is lazy (otherwise building long queries would trigger a call every time) and [so is the paginator constructor](https://github.com/django/django/blob/79a091820f46f00cba217a9e05daec855272c3ad/django/core/paginator.py).

Comment: Except the call does not sit in the void, you access the paginator to use it. And if you do `Article.objects.article_paginator.count` and then `Article.objects.article_paginator.num_pages`, you just triggered two queries. Which is not obvious because it looks like a regular property.